# ODBC_CONNECT cursor type conflict with SQLGetData in PHP with freeTDS and unixODBC

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, freetds, unixodbc

I have a PHP project running on my Gentoo Linux that uses FreeTDS & UnixODBC to connect to a MSSQL database on a Windows server. I have had this project working with this exact code for years now, but recently I had to update PHP when Gentoo no longer had a version 5.3 ebuild in portage and other system updates needed to happen.

The current versions of the various software being used is: 
**PHP is version 5.6.17

FreeTDS is version 0.91

UnixODBC is version 2.3.2-r1**

But now some of the very same queries that used to work perfectly return this error.

> PHP Warning:  odbc_fetch_object(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver
>   Manager]SQLGetData is not allowed on a forward only (non-buffered)
>   cursor, SQL state SL008 in SQLGetData in /home/XXXXX/XXXX.php on line
>   Y

Not all queries return this error, only some, but the same queries consistently return the same error.

A simple PHP program which will return this error is as follows:

```
$con = odbc_connect(DBNAME,UNAME,PW,SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC)
$query = "SELECT * FROM SomeTable"
$Output = odbc_exec($con,$query);
$return_array = array();
while($row = odbc_fetch_object($Output)){
#
        foreach($row as &$value){
                $value = mb_convert_encoding($value, "UTF-8", "Windows-1252");
        }
        unset($value);
        $return_array[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($return_array,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
odbc_close($con);
?>
```

Now this is definitely related to the 4th parameter supplied to **odbc_connect** when using **SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC**, the error is as I said above. When this is changed to **SQL_CUR_USE_IF_NEEDED** it returns the error:

> Warning: odbc_fetch_object(): No tuples available at this result index in /home/XXXXX/XXXX.php on line Y []

With a identical result for **SQL_CUR_USE_DRIVER**, or if it is left blank.

Again, two days ago this was all functional code across all queries. So something changed from PHP 5.3 to any version of php > 5.3. Every version of PHP has been tried from 5.4 to 7.0 (there is a PHP 7 ebuild in portage) and all produce the same errors.

Any help or direction in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know this is a year old, but I'm seeing the same thing with a very similar configuration and noticed it's only when a Text data-type is selected, and the data is still selected but there is a php WARNING for each `odbc_result` call on the Text data-type column.  Did you ever find a more permanent solution for the warnings?

Comment: I actually never did specifically. I kinda forgot about this question honestly. I feel like I must have just switched versions of PHP! But I welcome anyone else who does figure out what is going on with this letting the rest of us know!

Answer (score 2):

The first major hint I discovered was that it only happened when we did a SELECT with a text column along with other columns.  Using SELECT on a text column by itself did not throw the error. And selecting every other column except the text column did not throw the error.  We had just moved from SQL Server 2000 to 2008 so I was more than willing to try out VARCHAR(MAX) in favor of the text column we had to use in 2000.

`ALTER TABLE tbl_name ALTER COLUMN col_name VARCHAR(MAX) [NOT] NULL` fixed all these error messages for us. It transfers VARCHAR(MAX) just fine even when there were several KB of text returned. The old `Text` implementation left the column size at 2GB so I'm hypothesizing FreeTSD 0.91 has some size restriction.

Answer (score 0):

After extensive testing, the solution to this problem was to notice that these are just Warnings, not errors. They should have been thrown, but then also have the SQL execute.

However some glitch in one of these ODBC or TDS libraries was causing warnings to prevent the execution of the SQL. It is not a GREAT solution, but including **SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF** at the start of the query shut off the warnings, and now the code executes exactly as it did before.

```
$query = 'SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
          SELECT * FROM SomeTable';
```

Is what my query string looks like now. Not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this exact problem. Adding 'SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF' before my query solved the issue. thanks.

Freetds version : 0.91.112
PHP Version 5.3.29